# Data source for connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

What connection string should I use if SSMS connects to it using simply machine name, without instance name?

I mean it connects using the following string: PCName

I used to connect using PCName/SQLExpress. I cannot set correct connection string in my app in order to connect app to database on this machine.

How can I check what data source I should use? I've checked in Sql Server configuration that server instance named as SQLEXPRESS.

So I tried data source as:
.\SQLEXPRESS
PCName\SQLEXPRESS
.

I'm trying to connect to a service-based database, located in my app folder. So I'm using the following connection string:

data source=PCName;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\spareparts.mdf;integrated security=true;user instance=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;App=EntityFramework;

Comment: Whenever I struggle with connection strings in different environments I check this site and have found it to be very useful. Hope it helps: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

If SSMS connects via `PCName` then your application should be able to use `Data Source=PCName`. However it depends on whether your application is on the same machine as SSMS or not. If on a different machine it might not be able to connect for a variety of reasons. We can't speculate what the problem might be if all you do to describe the issue is "It won't connect" - what does that mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Make sure:

- SQL Browser service is started
- TCP/IP is enabled
- Add `Network=DBMSSOCN;` to the connection string
- You've also tried the IP address in addition to `PCName`
- Firewall isn't blocking the SQL Server port

Comment: I've added connection string I use. Could you please look at it?

Comment: @user1876232 please take out the `attachdbfilename`, `user instance` and `multipleActiveResultSets` nonsense and try again.

Comment: I'm using service=based database and db file stored with my app files. So I think I cannot take it out from connection string. Also I have this connection string generated automatically when I added Service-Based database item and linked to it with EntityFramework.